Copy to Google Drive on Mac works in shell script but not in cron or launchctl job
I am trying to setup a nightly task on my Mac to edit a file and then copy that file to my Google Drive which is accessible directly from my Mac's file system through Google Desktop integration. I have a simple bash script to test this that works properly when executed in the Terminal but fails when I try to add the script to cron or when executing through launchctl. The sample script is:
#!/bin/bash

echo "test data" > /Users/<user>/Scripts/Scratch/testfile.txt

cp /Users/<user>/Scripts/Scratch/testfile.txt /Users/<user>/Google*/My*/copied.txt

exit 0

"<user>" above is replaced by my actual user name in the script. My suspicion is that the spaces in the Google drive directory might be the issue. This is why I used '*' in the directory path. I also tried escaping the spaces as in the below snippet but that does not work in cron or launchctl either.
cp /Users/<user>/Scripts/Scratch/testfile.txt /Users/<user>/Google\ Drive/My\ Drive/copied.txt

The escaped spaces version also works when I run the script in Terminal. I also tried creating a link (both hard and symbolic) to the Google drive to avoid the spaces or the '*' workarounds in the script but that does not work in cron or launchctl either. The error I get when the cron job runs using the script with escaped spaces is this:
cp: /Users/<user>/Google Drive/My Drive/copied.txt: Operation not permitted

The error I get when I try '*' to avoid spaces in the path (again in cron only; works fine in Terminal) is this:
cp: /Users/<user>/Google*/My*/copied.txt: No such file or directory

It's hard to explain why all these approaches work in Terminal but not in cron or launchctl even though I'm using absolute paths everywhere.
MacBook Pro 2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5, 16 GB RAM running Sonoma 14.5
Additional info
After seeing a solution on the Apple support site, I tried giving cron full disk access and this actually fixed the problem for cron. However, the problem still persists for launchd even after granting launchd and launchctl the same full disk access.

The first error is a permission problem. If the user running the script via cron is the owner of /Users/<user>/Google Drive then It could be the SIP kicking in

It looks like you're close. Post the cron line you're using, thats the only thing missing from above. I'm speaking from a linux background (which also uses CRON), but I suspect they are similar in syntax.
I suspect you're letting cron run the task as default user:
* * * * * /your/cp/command
But since the file is in your Users directory, under a specific user, you may need to format your cron line like:
* * * * * <user> /your/cp/command
Posted this as a comment instead of an answer, as I'm not 100% sure CRON tasks work the same for MACs. But given your description, I bet this is close.

Thank you for the comments. Note that I was able to get this work with cron (see end of my post) after granting cron full disk access.  The line in the crontab is:
30 2 * * * /Users//Scripts/test.sh >~/Scripts/stdout.log 2>~/Scripts/stderr.log
The remaining problem is that I cannot get this to work with launchd.

Try give full disk access as described here but for /bin/bash
I did it for /bin/zsh for my case and it seems to work now.
I wonder though if giving the command line full disk access is a security issue?

If you provide a link, please also copy the relevant parts here, in case the link breaks at some point in the future
